# Producer/Consumer where producer is faster than consumer, should I use a double buffer or spsc_queue? (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, buffer, producer-consumer

I have a system that pulls data from a source into a buffer, that buffer is then written to a file using ofstream. Receiving the data is much faster than writing to disk, so I do not want to have to wait on the write function to receive additional data. I have 20 receivers, each writing to a separate binary file.

I basically need to thread the receive and write functions seperately so that the receiver can receive while the data from the last receive is being recorded to disk. I have tried a spsc_queue but it does not seem to work with a queue of buffers or structs (tried a struct with data and metadata in it). Does anyone have a recommended approach? I was thinking some sort of double buffer mechanism. Basically I want to minimize or remove wait time on the writer thread.

Comment: "_The `spsc_queue` class provides a single-writer/ **single-reader** fifo queue_" - Have you tried a `std::queue` and just add a mutex and a condition variable to guard it?

Comment: Problem is that if the queue is locked, the receiver cant receive. I need the receiver to always be receiving and writing to a buffer despite the speed of the writer.

Comment: It will only be locked very shortly whenever the producer is putting something into the queue. The producer would put something in and then call `notify_one` to get any waiting thread to wake up and extract the message. [Here's an untested idea](https://godbolt.org/z/9ePaq3nda)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: You're welcome. You'll have to review it carefully. I wrote it up in a haste and I think it will cause problems if you let the destructor shutdown the queue while threads are alive. All threads must stop using the queue before the queue is destroyed.